# Simplify a sum of log n/3i

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity, summarization

I have the following equation:

```
W(n) = w(n/3) + lg(n)
W(1) = Theta(1)
```

and I want to find its time complexity.
It can not be solved by the master theorem(can anyone confirm) so I have do that I by "hand"

If I think of it like a tree, there will only be one `W(1)` since Its just divide itself into one part and not several.

For all other `n != 1`, I can write them like the sum:

```
sum_{i=0}^{log3(n)-1}ln\frac{n}{3i}
```

My answer is for this question now is:

```
w(n) = sum_{i=0}^{log3(n)-1}ln\frac{n}{3i}
```

My problem now is that I do not know how to simplify this sum!

**Could anyone explain for me how to do it?**

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `n = 3^k`.

```
W(3^0) = 1
W(3^k) = W(3^(k-1)) + lg(3^k) = W(3^(k-1)) + lg(3)*k,
```

Substitute `T(k) = W(3^k)`.

```
T(0) = 1
T(k) = T(k-1) + lg(3)*k.
```

Verify by induction that

```
T(k) = 1 + lg(3) * sum_{j=1}^k j = 1 + lg(3) * (k+1)*k/2.
```

Undo the substitutions.

```
W(n) = 1 + lg(3) * (log3(n)+1)*log3(n)/2 = 1 + (lg(n)/lg(3)+1)*lg(n)/2.
```

Comment: 1.In step 3, how do you get the sum?


2.You just write that the equation has to be verified by induction you do not verify it, right?


3. Was my unsimplified solution wrong?

Comment: @user1991779 Well, substitute a couple times to observe that `T(k) = T(k-1) + lg(3)*k = T(k-2) + lg(3)*(k-1) + lg(3)*k = ...`, then generalize.

Comment: @user1991779 If by `3i` you mean `3^i`, then approximately (you've dropped the `W(1)` term on the floor, not that it matters much in the final accounting).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, It should be 3^i.

Answer (score 0):

It satisfies the Master Theorem.

Let `a=1`, `b=3`, and `f(n)=lg n`, so that [Case 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2) applies with `c=0` and `k=1`.  Therefore, `w(n)=Theta(lg^2 n)`.

You could analyze your final sum:

```
w(n) = sum_{i=1}^{log3(n)-1}ln\frac{n}{3i}
= sum_{i=1}^{log3(n)-1}ln(n/3)-ln i
= (log3(n)-1)ln(n/3)-ln((log3(n)-1)!)
= Theta(ln^2(n))-Theta(ln((log3(n)-1)!)
= Theta(ln^2(n))-Theta((log3(n)-1)ln(log3(n)-1))
= Theta(ln^2(n))-Theta(ln n * ln(ln n))
= Theta(ln^2(n))
```

Comment: "introduction to algorithm 3 edition" say that step to is valid if
f(n) = theta(n^(logb(a) ), not theta(n^(logb(a) * log^k(n) )!